# ARC and UIAlertView: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, uialertview, automatic-ref-counting

Here is how I show UIAlertView and the delegate clickedButtonAtIndex -

```
UIAlertView *alert =
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"title"
                               message: @"message"
                              delegate: self
                     cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel"
                     otherButtonTitles: @"Continue", nil];

    [alert show];


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    //something
}
```

This piece of code works perfectly without ARC. But with ARC it throws this error - 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x859d790'

Any ideas on why the delegate is throwing this error?

Comment: The delegate itself is being deallocated. How are you creating and managing that object?

Comment: @FirozeLafeer - the object that was calling this piece of code i.e. self was released by ARC. I made it a property and now it seems to work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 13):

Your delegate has been dealloc'd.  Double-check your code to make sure the object that is showing the alert and setting itself as the delegate is being retained somehow (ie: something in your app has a strong reference to it).

Comment: this was indeed my problem, which after this post i realised was because i'd copied a button over in the storyboard which still had a method attached that dealloc'd the viewController. Hence my other method, which WAS getting called and executing properly, couldn't carry out the tasks within theclickedButtonAtIndex. Hope this helps someone, thanks for your solution!

Comment: Also, search CocoaPods for UIAlertView and you'll find a number of blocks-based additions which will simplify using UIAlertView and eliminate the need to use UIAlertViewDelegate in your view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Similar can also happen if you forget the nil at the end after the last `otherButtonTitles` parameter:

`delegate: self
 cancelButtonTitle: @"No"
 otherButtonTitles: @"Yes",nil]; // don't forget the nil at the end here! (or it will crash first run)`

Interestingly enough it crashes only the first time you run the app. After that, it runs just fine.